# Code being removed in browser after file uploaded

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, browser

I'm trying to add the facebook like button, have follwed the steps from the Fb developers site, placed it where it needed to be, tried various other solutions for the like button not showing up. Can some one please explain why after I upload the file to the server, then look at the source code in the browser the code for the facebook like button is no longer there? Even the entire div tag surrounding the code is missing. When I look at the file that is on the server it contains the code for the button but the browser doesn't seem to recognize it.

I have read about having to create an API key(app ID), but have also heard it's not necessary.
Also, if the facebook account has settings like Country restrictions, it could mess up whether the button shows but the page I'm trying to set is to like a facebook page on another site. What am I missing?

Please help!

Here's what I have in code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

some more stuff in the body...

```
<div class="sideFigures">
    <div class="like">
      <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FEntertainmentIndustryIntroductionConvention&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=150&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font=verdana&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:150px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
    <img src="images/eiic figures.png" width="252" height="497" /> </div>
```

but when I look at source code from browser (in this example from IE), this is what I see:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

and the div containing the like button...

```
<div class="sideFigures"><img src="images/eiic figures.png" width="252" height="497" /></div>
```

Comment: Since SO currently does not have a mind-meld feature, you will need to post some code or a URL

Comment: Maybe your code is being stripped for security reasons, are you using a CMS?

Comment: Nope. Creating files and uploading through Dreamweaver. Looking at the files after upload on the server they still look the same, it's when I look at source code in the browser that the code for the button is gone.